# React: Is any descendant component a child component?

Tags: reactjs

Consider the following example:

```
function Travel(props) {
    return (
        <Welcome>
            <Country name={props.name}></Country>
        </Welcome>
    )
}

function Welcome(props) {
    return (
        <>
            <h1>Welcome to </h1>
            <div>{props.children}</div>
        </>
    )
}

function Country(props) {
    return (
        <h3>{props.name}</h3>
    )
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <Travel name="Japan"/>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

which outputs **Welcome to Japan**. In my understanding, **Country** is a grandchild of **Travel** and we are able to establish communication between these two components. `So, why are we saying Parent can only communicate with its children through props?` Unless we consider as child any component which lies inside return of the Parent component...

**So, my generic question is: All components that lie inside return of component A are children of A even if there is nested structure**?

```
function A(props){
  return (
   <B>
     <C>
       <D></D>
     </C> 
   </B>
  )
}
```

**In the above example B, C and D are all children of A? From A's perspective there is no difference between B, C and D?**

Comment: Actually `Country` is a child of `Travel`.

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: I want to know if it is a child or grandchild

Answer (score 3):

From the components' perspective `Country` is a grand grand child of `Travel`.

Here is the resulting component tree I took from react developer tools:

(When you inspect you can see which component is rendered by which at the bottom right corner)

```
Travel/
├── Welcome/          -- rendered by Travel
├──├── h1             -- rendered by Welcome, Travel
├──├── div/           -- rendered by Welcome, Travel
├──├──├── Country/    -- rendered by Travel
├──├──├──├── h3       -- rendered by Country, Travel
```

You can also imagine there is 'recursion tree'. In this recursion tree `Country` is a child of `Travel`.

`Travel` component doesn't return single node but it returns sub-tree.

Which should look something like:

```
{
  "type": "Welcome",
  "props": {
    "children":[{
      "type": "Country",
      "props": {
        "name": "Japan"
      }
    }]
  }
}
```

To create such sub-tree it first renders `Country`.

edit:

You mentioned `So, why are we saying Parent can only communicate with its children through props?`

`Welcome` is a only child of `Travel`. You are basically rendering new react component(called `Country`) and passing it as a props. It's then passed deep into component tree until it finds its parent. So you are communicating via props. See https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html

Following ugly code is not really equivalent of jsx version but it explains situation well.

```
function Travel(props) {
  const country = React.createElement(
    "Country",
    {name: props.name},
    []
  );
  return React.createElement(
    "Welcome",
    {},
    [country]
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The generic answer is no. From A's perspective, **there is a difference** between B, C and D.

Let's have a look at the example below.

```
// Passing the props {data:"From one"}
export function One(props) {
console.log(props);
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      one
      <Two>
        <Three></Three>
      </Two>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

function Two(props) {
  console.log(props);
  return <React.Fragment>Two {props.children} </React.Fragment>;
}

function Three(props) {
  console.log(props);
  return "Three";
}
```

is a similar structure to what you have mentioned. 
As you can see from the output below - the props are not being passed on to the grandchild `Three`.

The logs are Props of `One` `Two` and `Three` in sequence.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Since `Country` is accessed from `Travel`, I would say it's a child of `Travel`. It happens to be inside other component in the layout, but that component (`Welcome`) doesn't interact with it in any way. Now, if you had `Country` inside `Welcome.render`, then it would be a child of `Welcome` and a grandchild of `Travel`.

Answer (score 0):

`Country` is a child of `Travel`, because you're just passing the prop without prop drilling.

If you would pass name to the `Welcome`, and inside pass it down to `Country` then it would be a "grandchild".

Look at it not as DOM node inheritance, but component props scope. And you will see that both `Welcome` and `Country` are children of `Travel`.